# sh file is not running on nginx web server

Tags: webserver, html, nginx, openwrt, sh

I am using nginx web server in openwrt and made page using shell script and html. The issue is shell commands are not running but html tags are running. Below is my code.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
echo '<html>'
echo '<head>'
echo '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">'
echo '<img src="../image.png" alt="Lakshmi Tours and Travels" style="width:435px;height:312px;">'
echo '</head>'
echo '<title>Jaydeep Tours and Travels</title>'
echo '<center><h1 align='center'>Welcome To Jaydeep Tours and Travels</h1></center>'
echo '<body><center><h1 align='center'>Movies</h1></center>'
echo '
<style type="text/css">
h1 {
color: #2B2301;
margin-top: 0.9cm;
background-color: #DDD4BC;
}
#movie:before {
content: url('../bullet.png');
padding-right: 7px;
}
#movie {
font-size: 25px; 
text-decoration: none;
color: #6E6E6E; 
margin-left: 0.8cm;
}
p {
font-size: 20px;
color: #6E6E6E;
text-align:center;
}
</style>'
list=$(ls -l /mnt/sda2 | grep "^d" | awk -F" " '{print $9}' | sed 's/Songs//g')
list1=$(echo $list | wc -w)
if [ $list1 = 0 ]; then
files=$(ls -p /mnt/sda2 | grep -v / | sed 's/index.html//g')
files1=$(echo $files | wc -w)
j=1
while [ $j -le $files1 ]
do
videofile=$(echo $files | cut -d' ' -f$j)
video = "/$videofile"
ext=$(echo $videofile | sed 's/.*\.//')
videoname=$(echo $videofile | cut -f1 -d".")
if [ $ext = "mp4" ]; then
    echo ' 
    <div style="text-align:center">
    <video width="400" height="260" controls>
        <source src="'$video'" type="video/mp4">
        </video></div>'
    echo '<p>'$videoname'</p>'
elif [ $ext = "webm" ]; then
    echo ' 
    <div style="text-align:center">
    <video width="400" height="260" controls>
        <source src="'$video'" type="video/webm">
        </video></div>'
    echo '<p>'$videoname'</p>'
elif [ $ext = "ogv" ] || [ $ext = "ogg" ]; then
    echo ' 
    <div style="text-align:center">
    <video width="400" height="260" controls>
        <source src="'$video'" type="video/ogg">
        </video></div>'
    echo '<p>'$videoname'</p>'
fi
j=$((j+1))
done
fi
i=1
while [ $i -le $list1 ]
do
folder=$(echo $list | cut -d' ' -f$i)
echo '<a href="#" onclick="myFunction(this); return false;"             
id="movie">'$folder'</a></font><br><br>'
i=$((i+1))
done
echo '
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction (movieElement) {
var mtype = movieElement.text
window.location.href = "luci2.sh?"+mtype;
}
</script>'
echo '<br><br><p1><center>For more movies and songs download the </p1><a             
href="/TvBus.apk" style="text-decoration:none">apk</a></font>'
echo '</body></html>'
exit 0
```

and this is my nginx.conf file

```
user nobody nogroup;
worker_processes  1;
events {
worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
include mime.types;
index index.php index.html index.htm;
default_type text/html;

sendfile on;
keepalive_timeout 65;
gzip on;

gzip_min_length  1k;
gzip_buffers     4 16k;
gzip_http_version 1.0;
gzip_comp_level 2;
gzip_types       text/plain application/x-javascript text/css application/xml;
gzip_vary on;
server {
    listen       80;        # Port, make sure it is not in conflict with another http daemon.
    server_name  tvbus.xyz; # Change this, reference -> http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html
fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
fastcgi_buffers 4 32k;
fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 32k;
fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 32k;
client_body_timeout 10;
client_header_timeout 10;
send_timeout 60;        # 60 sec should be enough, if experiencing a lot of timeouts, increase this.
output_buffers 1 32k;
postpone_output 1460;

root   /mnt/sda2;       # Your document root, where all public material is.

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    include        fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

    if (-f $request_filename) {
        # Only throw it at PHP-FPM if the file exists (prevents some PHP exploits)
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:1026;     # The upstream determined above
    }
}
}
}
```

Please help me in this, it will be great appreciation.[image: this is my output of sh file]

Comment: You are trying to load a shell script as a webpage? like index.sh?

Comment: You don't have any configuration in place to actually tell it to run the script. It won't just happily execute shell script you put in the web directory.

Comment: Btw, the HTML is not 'running' either, it's just that your browser tries to make sense of what is being sent to it (the total script), and will try it's best to render a webpage out of that.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to load shell script as webpage

Comment: When I was using uhttpd instead of nginx it was working like a charm. But for some reasons I am using nginx

Comment: You simply can't load a shell script as a web page with nginx

Comment: What should I do to run shell script on web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by using nginx and uhttpd both on different port.